# Combine COUNTA and COUNTIF formulas?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to count cells in a range by their color and also by the value in the cell. For example, I want to know how many cells are both Teal AND contain the number 3 in a selected range.

I’ve had success with the formulas separately, but no luck combining the two.
Here are the formulas separately:

```
=COUNTA(valuesByColor("#21aabc", "#000000", 'Colour sheet'!F3:BQ18))

=COUNTIF((F3:BQ18),"3")
```

As you can see in the screenshot, I know 290 cells are the color Teal, but how can I also tell how many Teal cells contain the value 0, 1, 2, and so on?

[image: Screenshot of current spreadsheet]

Comment: Welcome.  _but no luck combining the two_ What have you tried? Show us your work. Have you considered `AND()` [Doc Ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301)?

Comment: @Tedinoz I've edited the original question to contain a screenshot. It's unusual as I am not working with columns, but a whole range.
I've tried using COUNTIFS and AND, but not sure if I am using them correctly.

Comment: you need to rewrite `valuesByColor` to include values as well

Comment: @TheMaster Do you mean write a custom function?

Comment: @Tedinoz It is already a custom function. OP is not showing it's code